# Synchronize podcasts with Rhythmbox to an iPod

Tags: ubuntu, sync, ipod, podcasts, rhythmbox

Is it possible to synchronize podcasts with Rhythmbox to an iPod? If not, is there another application in Ubuntu that can do it?

By synchronizing podcasts I mean doing the same thing iTunes does. Putting the newer ones on the device, and then removing them as they are listened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the best app for podcats in ubuntu that i found was [gpodder](http://gpodder.org/)
It has a sync to device that suports IPOD, and also you can upload your subscriptions to the online account to keep your list synced across computers

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no.  There is an [open request](http://www.wuglug.org.uk/Rhythmbox/PodcastPlugin) to have a plugin that does this added to Rhythmbox.  I know the older 1.4 version of [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/) did this, but the KDE4 version of it has changed a lot & I just don't know if it's supported in the 2.x version.  Amarok is currently at 2.2.  It is planned to be the default audio player in Karmic's version of Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Sure Rhythmbox will do it without any hickup as well as many other Linux Music Jukeboxes like Banshee.

Comment: Well, how does it do? How do you subscribe to a podcast with it and how do you tell it to copy the new unlistened episodes t an iPod?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the best alternative but you should be able to install itunes on top of linux using wine.

http://mediakey.dk/~cc/itunes-on-linux-ubuntu/