# Rhythmbox - put a playlist on my iPod

Tags: ubuntu, ipod, rhythmbox

I have an old iPod nano and currently use iTunes in Windows to management. However, I'm trying to switch to Ubuntu. So far, iPod management is one major holdup.

Besides [being unable to easily manage podcasts](https://superuser.com/questions/59959/synchronize-podcasts-with-rhythmbox-to-an-ipod), I also don't see a way to create a playlist and put it on my iPod.

I can create a playlist on the computer in Rhythmbox, but I can't drag and drop it onto the iPod.

I can create a playlist on the iPod itself, put I can't drag and drop songs from my library into it. If I right-click the songs, I can add them to playlists on the computer, but not on the iPod.

**How can I create a playlist of music in Rhythmbox and sync it to my iPod?**

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Nerdfest - 10.04.

Answer (score 3):

See here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12475542

It prompts you for all your rhythmbox playlists and lets you pick which ones to sync. Moves the files over. Creates a playlist on the device as well. It is a sync not a copy -- so other music files on your device on the Music folder get removed.

Could not be any easier.

After many hours of searching that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. There's no work-around yet.

[See this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/+bug/496681)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing gstreamer. To do that, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins*
```